# Dataframe filter a column if it is in an interval data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe array which included some column and one of them is 'time'
i want to filter the rows which time is in a specific interval

To simplify the problem i make a data frame with an integer value and an integer interval

```py
data=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
interval=pd.Interval(1,4)
data[data['A'] in interval]
```

It shows: 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

but the expected result is [2,3,4]

Comment: there isn't a builtin way to do this in pandas currently but is something that will eventually get added (no definitive timeline yet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `between`

[`pandas.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) will return a boolean mask that can be used to filter the dataframe.

```
data[data.A.between(1, 4)]

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

---

#### `query`

[`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) can be used to filter as well

```
data.query('1 <= A <= 4')

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

---

#### `isin`

[`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) can be used in the special integer case using `range`.  Similar to `between` we create a boolean mask.

```
data[data.A.isin(range(1, 5))]

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any possibility to use the interval in function?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  `pandas.Interval` is meant to represent a hashable thing that can represent a category.  It's used in splitting data up into buckets where each bucket is represented by an interval.  We can then use these intervals as indices.  Of course, that can be changed by the Pandas devs to accomidate this sort of thing but I doubt they would.

Comment: What do you think about ```data[data.A.apply(lambda x : x in interval)]``` is it a good way?

Comment: It's clever but slow considering the `apply`.  A more pithy way to do the same thing but also not recommended `data[data.A.map(interval.__contains__)]` or `data[[*map(interval.__contains__, data.A)]]`

Comment: so the `between` and `isin` examples aren't quite right in general: `between` doesn't handle mixed inequalities (i.e. in the example the interval is open on the right and closed on the left) and the `isin` example doesn't handle fractional values (i.e. 1.5 is in the example interval)

Comment: @root I agree about `isin` but will be correct with appropriate choice of limits if we are dealing with integer only.  For `between` you can choose the boundaries to be inclusive or not with the option `inclusive=True` or `inclusive=False` but in either case, you don't get **mixed** inclusion... so agree with you there as well.  `query` handles it elegantly and the rest is for everyone else (-:

Answer (score 4):

Using your `interval`

```
data.loc[(data.A>=interval.left) & (data.A<interval.right)]
Out[245]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
s = data[data.A.between(interval.left+1, interval.right)]

print(s)
   A
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Or using `Boolean indexing`:

```
l = data[(data.A > interval.left) & (data.A <= interval.right)]

print(l)
   A
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any possibility to use the interval in function?

Comment: `between` doesn't quite work in general as it doesn't handle mixed inequalities (i.e. in the example the interval is open on the right and closed on the left); adding 1 to the open endpoint doesn't account for fractional values (i.e. 1.1 is in the example interval)