# sort rows by quantiles in pd data frame and find indices of initial data frame in each quantile

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df and I want to sort each row by deciles, i.e. for that row which are the lowest to biggest values bagged in deciles.
pd.qcut takes 1D array.. for the second row, the corresponding deciles are:

```
pd.qcut(mm.values[1],10,duplicates='drop').value_counts()

(-0.754, -0.212]     240
(-0.212, -0.12]      234
(-0.12, -0.0436]     235
(-0.0436, 0.0343]    236
(0.0343, 0.117]      238
(0.117, 0.214]       235
(0.214, 0.344]       236
(0.344, 0.536]       236
(0.536, 0.948]       236
(0.948, 9.55]        237
```

Is there a way to get the indexes of the specific columns that fall into these deciles for that row?

EDITED :

```
 dec = mm.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,10, duplicates='drop'), axis=1)
```

I did this and now my data set has in each position the decile (for each row) that this column belongs to. Is there a way that I can call this specific position by decile?
My data set now looks like this [sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzmj2.png)
I cannot put labels because of the uneven number of quantiles in each row due to missing values.

Comment: can you share some sample of your data?

Comment: Yes I edited my question

Comment: can you post your expected output also?

Comment: This output is for row 1 right you want to do it for all ?

Comment: Please add sample data as text rather than image.

Comment: I would like to know: for each date (row ~I guess will have to put this in a for loop as qcut takes 1D array), which indices (columns/stocks) fall in the corresponding deciles? I'm interested in the top and bottom deciles actually. This command yields a categorical array. With value_counts() I get a series and I can call each position with iloc but I get the number of stocks which fall in this decile and not the decile itself. In summary: row 1: decile 1: index 0,3,9...

Comment: This is the best I can achieve with copy paste I suppose..

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832639/dataframe-filter-a-column-if-it-is-in-an-interval-data-type

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Comment: No thank you very much ! Eventually as I wanted the min and max deciles, I did this:

Comment: np.argwhere(dec.values[t] == pd.qcut(mm.values[t],10, duplicates='drop').categories.max())

Comment: If your problem is solved and you have the answer. post your answer and mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question but I guess this code will help you:

```
def func(row):
    for decl in (pd.qcut(row.values, 3, duplicates='drop')):
        print(decl, row.values)
        print('col names:', [row.index[idx] for idx,i in enumerate(row.values) if i in range(int(decl.left),int(decl.right)+1) ])
    print()

df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The thing is I cannot index with pd.qcut cause it is categorical... I get: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 0):

```
np.argwhere(dec.values[t] == pd.qcut(mm.values[t],10, duplicates='drop').categories.max())
```